# Listen to multiple blocs on parent bloc

Tags: flutter, forms, dart, state, bloc

I have a MainFormBloc which is in charge of submitting the form. I have a username and password bloc each with their separate logic. Once the username is valid, the Username bloc will have the UsernameValid state and for the password once is valid will have the PasswordValid state.

I'm having trouble knowing how will I implement the logic for when both username and password bloc emits valid states then the MainFormBloc should emit the FormIsReadyState.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It really sounds to me like the MainFormBloc actually should handle all the logic, since it sounds like both username and password are part of the form....

But, if that is not the case, then you should use a `BlocListener` for the username and password blocs respectively which will trigger when those are valid, and then in turn call methods in the MainFormBloc to notify when they are valid.